# C Memory free in loop error -> invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, memory, stack, malloc

I have a problem with `free()` of a `malloc`'ed `char` pointer in a loop.

In `char *x=malloc(30)` I'm storing a string that I'm pushing to the stack with `add(x,queue)`. The problem is that I'm `malloc`-ing it every iteration, so I need to `free` it in every iteration, otherwise I have a memory leak in valgrind. But if I put `free(x);` at the end of the while loop, valgrind has a problem with `strcmp` :

```
Invalid read of size 1
at 0x403045D: strcmp

by 0x048871: main(main.c 149) = else if(!strcmp(x,l))
address is 0 bytes inside block of size 30 free d

by 0x80488b8: main(main.c 164) = free(x);
block was allocked at
at 0x402c17c:malloc by main(main.c 129) =char *x=malloc(30);
```

It's odd, because I do not need that `char *x` until another allocation.
Is there a way of allocating it in a different way?

```
while ((a = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (a == '<'){
        act = 1;
    }
    if (act == 1) {
        char *x=malloc(30);
        scanf("%29[^>]s",x);

        if(*x=='/'){

            void *l;
            l=pop_from_queue(queue);

            if(l==NULL)
                valid=1;
            else if(!strcmp(x+1,l))
                valid=0;
            else
                valid=1;

            act=0;
        }else{
            push_to_queue(queue,x); //push to stack
            count++;
            act=0;

        }
        free(x);       
     }
}
```

init stack:

```
typedef struct {
  void **data;
  int head;
  int size;
  int count;

} queue_t;

queue_t* create_queue(int capacity){
  queue_t *queue=calloc(sizeof(queue_t),sizeof(queue_t));
  queue->head=0;
  queue->data=calloc(capacity+10,sizeof(void*));
  queue->count=0;
  queue->size=capacity+1;
  return queue;
}
```

pop function:

```
void* pop_from_queue(queue_t *queue){

  if(queue->count==0)
    return NULL;
  else
    queue->count--;

  if(queue->head<0)
    return NULL;

  if(queue->head!=0)
    queue->head--;

  return queue->data[queue->head];

}
```

push function:

```
bool push_to_queue(queue_t *queue, void *data){
  if(queue->count==queue->size){
    queue->size+=10;
    queue->data=realloc(queue->data,queue->size*sizeof(void*));
  }
  queue->data[queue->head++]=data;
  queue->count++;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I also encourage you to delete x when `(*x=='/')` to not have a memory leak, and to help to not do `x++` but `strcmp(x+1,l)`

Comment: That´s true, but I will never put longer word than 20.

Comment: I need x for strcmp(x,l) so I can´t delete it. :( That x++; is there for deleting first char from x, so I can compare it with poped string from stack

Comment: So I need to free(x++)? or change x++; <

Comment: @xing this why I proposed to not do ++x, to not have after to decrease it to do the free. After of course the right way is more to not allocate before to read and be sure the _add_ need to be done.

Comment: @Dzoey as I said the minimal change is to remove the `x++;` and modify the _strcmp_ to be `strcmp(x+1,l)`, allowing you to `free(x)` after without having to do `free(x-1)`  not very clear

Comment: @Dzoey your stuff with _act_ is also very strange and complicated for nothing, you don't need that variable

Comment: Ok, so after strcmp i write x--; free(x); . That seems ok but if(*x=='/') is not fulfilled its still giving me error at free(x);

Comment: @Dzoey I don't understand `but if(*x=='/') is not ...` because I don't know what additional changes you did

Comment: @Dzoey I see your editing and you missed to move the `free(x);` outside the _else_ branch

Comment: Now, after changing strcmp(x+1,l) all memory leaks are gone but its still givim error with strcmp at line else if(!strcmp(x+1,l)) because adres is 0 bytes inside block of size 30 free d by free(x); mallocked by line char *x=malloc(30);

Comment: @Dzoey I think the code you execute is **not** the code you show, because here the memory leak is still present and because except if _add()_ or _pop_from_queue()_ destruct the memory or you enter more than 29 characters there is no reason to see the heap destructed. The reason or your problem is elsewhere, not on the code you show

Comment: yea, that´s true. If I try strcmp(x+1,''hello'') its working. So problem is somewhere at pop function but its wierd because I was using it before in other programs and it was workong :/

Comment: @Dzoey to check your _pop_from_queue_ we also need the _add_ and the definition of `queue_t`

Comment: I try to printf pop_from_queue. It give me the right string but valgrind gave me more erros with invalid read of size 1. Address is 0 bytes inside block of 30 free d by free(x); mallocked at char *x=malloc(30); . So po from queue is dependent on char *x;

Comment: @Dzoey and found and answer, sorry I don't see the problem before even i was so simple. So in your first proposal the free was just on the wrong branch of the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not do `free(x);` after you `push_to_queue(queue,x);`, you have to `free(x);` only when `if(*x=='/')`

Because you freed the pushed value, when you pop it you get an already free memory, and that one is used by *strcmp*

So simple I didn't see it before !

Note : you need to free the value you get through the pop if not NULL whatever the result of *strcmp*

Comment: That´s right. But is there a way to free all mallocked X after while loop end? Now I´m not getting valgrind error but I have 1 leaked block for every X mallocked. Do I need to store them somewhere else so I can delete them after loop?

Comment: @Dzoey after the while just do something like that :  `void *l; while((l = pop_from_queue(queue)) != 0) free(l);`

Comment: Thank you very much. It´s working now. I need to also free(l); in if(*x=='/') condition. GJ

Comment: @Dzoey yes, I said you to do ;-) I also encourage you to simplify your code, for instance  the use of the variable _act_ is useless

Answer (score 0):

You do not verify that `scanf()` actually processed any data before dereferencing `x`.

If `scanf()` doesn't read any data and store it in `x`, any read from `x` will be invalid.